# NFT Picture and metadata detail not display testnet opensea (polygon mumbai)

Tags: solidity, polygon, opensea

The minted NFT item and detail not displayed on test net Opensea while rinkeby network working properly . pls kindly advise where gone wrong

https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/squirrel-eqf09pjm5s

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xEE21cF8F15e487968706C5bbD15837c50D1aB2a1

contract.sol

```
constructor() ERC721("Squirrel", "SRL") {
    
    _baseTokenURI = "QmSrH7nkakj9T7FUKSD48ENcJusvnaTdmdJV9AXhLPHNst/";  //metadata url
```

the ipfs metadata and images file working fine.

json    =  ipfs/QmSrH7nkakj9T7FUKSD48ENcJusvnaTdmdJV9AXhLPHNst/0

```
{"name": "Squirrel #0", "description": "Squirrel NFT . limited edition 1,000!", "image": "ipfs://QmczVxRT66QqC7HeYh6ZnT8QLd2qoAiqW8DfhX4ghG7bVw/0.png", "attributes": [{"trait_type": "Background", "value": "blue"}, {"trait_type": "Body", "value": "maroon"}, {"trait_type": "Eyes", "value": "standard"}, {"trait_type": "Clothes", "value": "blue_dot"}, {"trait_type": "Held Item", "value": "nut"}]}
```

images :

ipfs.io/ipfs/QmczVxRT66QqC7HeYh6ZnT8QLd2qoAiqW8DfhX4ghG7bVw/0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first understand how Opensea reads your contract to retrieve the meta-data –

From Opensea's [documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards)

> To find this URI, we use the tokenURI method in ERC721 and the uri method in ERC1155. First, let's look closely at the tokenURI method in the Creature contract.

Further:

> The tokenURI function in your ERC721 or the uri function in your ERC1155 contract should return an HTTP or IPFS URL, such as https://opensea-creatures-api.herokuapp.com/api/creature/3. When queried, this URL should in turn return a JSON blob of data with the metadata for your token. You can see an example of a simple Python server for serving metadata in the OpenSea creatures repo here.

Further for IPFS specific

> If you use IPFS to host your metadata, your URL should be in the format ipfs://. For example, ipfs://QmTy8w65yBXgyfG2ZBg5TrfB2hPjrDQH3RCQFJGkARStJb

Now let us see what your [contract returns the tokenURI](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xee21cf8f15e487968706c5bbd15837c50d1ab2a1#readContract) for a minted token (in this case, tokenID: 0)

[image]

As you can see, your contract is returning `QmSrH7nkakj9T7FUKSD48ENcJusvnaTdmdJV9AXhLPHNst/0` which is incomplete since it does not contain a base (`ipfs://`) to resolve from.

Your `tokenURI` method should return the complete resolvable IPFS URI to your JSON file: `ipfs://QmczVxRT66QqC7HeYh6ZnT8QLd2qoAiqW8DfhX4ghG7bVw/0`

Additionally, you should make sure your JSON file is query-ready by manually visiting the IPFS URL through any IPFS enabled browser.

Here's an example of [doodle contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8a90cab2b38dba80c64b7734e58ee1db38b8992e#readContract) returning URI:

[image: Doodle's contract returning tokenURI for tokenID 0]

Comment: alright  Tanishq thanks for your detail explanation

Comment: hi i having another issue below thread regarding address array invalid in polygon network as well.

can pls assist to take a look?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123714/error-invalid-address-on-polygon-network

Comment: Hi, my tokenURI returns `ipfs://QmUNekrvZj4MWezLX9wnBtpLC4M3E1Ea6SJgyMN739gYGv/1.json`. Do I need to remove the `.json`? I can't get the nft to show on opensea as well.

Comment: @yongho You don't need to, but you do need to check if the link itself works. I just uploaded an NFT with `.json`, and it works as normal. Your link doesn't seem working btw.